# XSLT if statement does't work, how do I get it to work?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to check if two variables are the same. When the variables are the same, I want to output code.

This is my code right now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:call-template name="item" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="item">
  <xsl:for-each select="item">

    <xsl:variable name="currentItemTheme"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="theme">{$audienceTheme}</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentItemTheme"/> &#160;&#160; <xsl:value-of select="$theme"/> <br/>

    <xsl:if test="$currentItemTheme = $theme">
      test <br/>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The variable `{$audienceTheme}` is loaded into the template with Smarty PHP and works correctly. The value for it is `Wellness-arrangementen`.

This is how the output looks right now:

[image]

You can see that 'Wellness-arrangementen' is the `{$audienceTheme}` variable and that that works.

Now the problem is the if statement under the variables doesn't work. As you can see in the image the second row of text has the same value for both `$currentItemTheme` and `$theme`. But the **if statement** doesn't output `'test <br/>'`. Does anyone know why this **if statement** doesn't work?

Comment: Start with pure XSLT/XPath `<xsl:variable name="theme" select="'Wellness-arrangementen'"/>` and show us some way how to reproduce the problem, posting images doesn't allow us to see or test whether there are any whitespace or other character differences. And show us the exact XML input (e.g. `item` and `title` elements).

Comment: is it possible that there are subtle differences, such as leading or trailing whitespace that make it difficult for you to see the difference? Try concatenating some character before and after the values, or apply `normalize-space()` when comparing:  `test="normalize-space($currentItemTheme) = normalize-space($theme)"`

Comment: I think I know the problem. My guess is the PHP variable {$audienceTheme runs after the XML feed is loaded. That's why the value does print in the output, but why it can't be used in the if statement, because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: instead of some find/replace of tokens after the fact, send that value into your stylesheet as an external `xsl:param` and use it

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have acces to the source files, it's just a PHP/smarty engine in the Email Service Provider I use. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @MartinHonnen yeah then it does work! But using normalize-space and smarty trim on the {$audienceTheme) doesn't work, so I guess it's the problem I described above. Thanks though!

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP/smarty so I can't explain the result you get but if you need help with a particular combination of XSLT and some other tool or language it is a good idea to use various tags for the different tools or languages used.

Comment: Did really tries @MadsHansen suggestion: 
test="normalize-space($currentItemTheme) = normalize-space($theme)"
?

Answer (score 1):

In stead of using Smarty PHP to get some dynamic data in the xsl, I would suggest to use the XSLTProcessor->setParam() method like this:

```
<?php
$xmlDocument = new DOMDocument;
$xslDocument = new DOMDocument;

if ($xmlDocument->load($xmlUri) && $xslDocument->load($xslUri)) {

    $xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xsltProc->setParam('audienceTheme', 'Wellness-arrangementen');
    if ($xsltProc->importStyleSheet($xslDocument)) {
        $transformed = $xsltProc->transformToXML($xmlDocument);
    }
}
```

and your xslt could the look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:param name="audienceTheme"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
      
    <xsl:variable name="currentItemTheme" select="title/text()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentItemTheme"/> &#160;&#160; <xsl:value-of select="$audienceTheme"/> <br/>
    
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($currentItemTheme) = normalize-space($audienceTheme)">
      <xsl:text>test</xsl:text>
      <br/>
    </xsl:if>
      
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey Siebe! That would be a nice solution but unfortunately I don't have acces to the PHP file in this case. Will remember this if I ever need to do something similar, thanks!